# Killing a subprocess exits Python program

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

```
def playvid(self):
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen("gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink", shell=True)
    time.sleep(3)
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc1.pid),signal.SIGTERM)
```

This function gets called when I press a button (created using TK library). After 3 seconds my entire program (along with the GUI screen) gets killed instead of only the subprocess. How do I rectify this and make sure that only the subprocess proc1 is killed.

Comment: From the doc: os.getpgid(pid)

    Return the process group id of the process with process id pid. If pid is 0, the process group id of the current process is returned.

Comment: how do I kill the particular subprocess alone?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation for [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) there are several methods to choose from:

**Popen.send_signal(signal)**

Sends the signal signal to the child.

On Windows, SIGTERM is an alias for terminate().

**Popen.terminate()**

Stop the child. On Posix OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child.

**Popen.kill()**

Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends SIGKILL to the child. On Windows kill() is an alias for terminate().

I would use:

```
proc1.terminate()
```