# Not able to kill Subprocess in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to open a python code say test_2.py from another python code say test_1.py and then kill the Test_2.py executing window.

test_2.py contains :

```
def hello():
    print "Hello World"

while 1:
    hello()
```

In test_1.py I am reading from a speech recognition for some command and matching it internally. Based on the command i either start the test_2 execution or kill it.

I am able to start the subprocess in a new console window, but when I want to terminate the operation the test_1 window closes and the terminate command does not close the test_2 console window. I have tried using p.pid, p.kill, p.terminate and even threads but was not able to get the desired results. Could anyone please let me know what i am missing here as well as what is the right way to do what I am trying to do ?

test_1.py code :

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading
import os, sys, signal
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
import time
import psutil

COMMAND_Kill_1 = 'power off'
COMMAND_Kill_2 = 'switch off'

COMMAND_Start_1 = 'initialize'
COMMAND_Start_2 = 'initialise'

COMMAND_Upper_1 = 'upper case'
COMMAND_Upper_2 = 'uppercase'

def active_listen():
    global p

    recog = sr.Recognizer()

    print 'Say Command'

    with sr.Microphone() as src:
        audio = recog.listen(src)

    msg = ''

    try:
        msg = recog.recognize_google(audio)
        #print msg
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print "Not able to recognize the input"
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print "Google request error"
    except:
        print "Unknown exception ocurred"
    finally:


        if ( (msg == COMMAND_Kill_1) or (msg == COMMAND_Kill_2) ):
            print msg

            Popen('taskkill /F /T /PID '+ str(p.pid))

        elif ( (msg == COMMAND_Upper_1) or (msg == COMMAND_Upper_2) ):
            print msg.upper()

        elif ( (msg == COMMAND_Start_1) or (msg == COMMAND_Start_2) ):
            print msg
            p = Popen('python test_2.py', shell=False, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
            print p.pid

        else:
            print msg

        return msg

while 1:
    active_listen()
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42803255/killing-a-subprocess-exits-python-program

Comment: yes tried it, not working

Comment: To clarify you do: console test_1.py Start; and then test_1.py END

Comment: Not able to get you... but to clarify -  Start and END - are the commands written in a text file which my python code is reading....now based on this need to start / kill another python code ... and yes order is Start and then END. If possible can you please replicate the code in your system and check if it is working ?

Comment: You execute test_1.py twice, so your `p.pid` at END is invalid

Comment: hey added the actual code .. it is a speech recognition code that i am testing...use this instead.

Comment: Make `p` **global**and it should work

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks. !